# Django admin add more option oneToMany relationship

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a situation where I have a question and question have multiple test_cases and outputs. I want add more option like + to have many test_cases and outputs for a single question.
Here is my Model:

```
from django.db import models
from questions.models import Question

class Testcase(models.Model):
question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
standard_input = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
standard_output = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.standard_input
```

And here is my admin.py:

```
from .models import Question
from .models import Testcase

class TestcaseInline(admin.TabularInline):
model = Testcase
extra = 1

class TestcaseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
pass
list_display = ('question', 'standard_input', 'standard_output')
inlines = [ TestcaseInline, ]
search_fields = ('question', 'st_input')
list_display_links = ('question',)
list_per_page = 20


admin.site.register(Testcase, TestcaseAdmin)
```

I am getting this error:
": (admin.E202) 'testcases.Testcase' has no ForeignKey to 'testcases.Testcase'."

What wrong I am doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are adding to wrong ModelAdmin for `TestcaseInline`. It should be added to `Question` Model Admin.

```
class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ TestcaseInline, ]


admin.site.register(Question, QuestionAdmin)
```

Comment: Thanks, @rudra, I was putting these inside testcases app only but should be inside questions apps. Again thanks for the help.